# How to rewrite node js request

Tags: node.js, express, request

it is possible to modify node js requested url??
browser sending me request like this

```
http://localhost/user/add
```

when its comes to server i want to add api in my current request i mean like below request.

```
http://localhost/api/user/add
```

for this i have written one middle ware but look like its not working.

```
app.use('*', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.baseUrl.indexOf('api') == -1) {
    req.baseUrl = '/api' + req.baseUrl;
    console.log('req.baseUrl');
    console.log(req.baseUrl);
  }
  next();
});
```

above code not working please tell me what's i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try assign the **req.url** and **req.originalUrl**. They are key point for rewrite request. https://expressjs.com/en/api.html

> This property is much like req.url; however, it retains the original request URL, allowing you to rewrite req.url freely for internal routing purposes. For example, the “mounting” feature of app.use() will rewrite req.url to strip the mount point.

On the other hand, [express-urlrewrite](https://github.com/kapouer/express-urlrewrite) is an open-sourced library for express url rewrite. You could be inspired from it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-fire router to handle updated urls:

```
app.use('*', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.baseUrl.indexOf('api') == -1) {
    req.url = '/api' + req.url;
    req.originalUrl = '/api' + req.originalUrl; //update all 3 just to be 
    safe.
    req.baseUrl = '/api' + req.baseUrl;
    console.log('req.baseUrl');
    console.log(req.baseUrl);
    app.handle(req, res); //re-fire router to handle updated urls
  }
  next();
});
```